# How to set the selected value and text of a drop down menu on page load with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

within an asp.net page I have a predefined drop down menu

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="queryterm dropdownSpacer" ID="ddResultNum" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="10 Results " Value="10" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="20 Results" Value="20" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="30 Results" Value="30" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="40 Results" Value="40" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="50 Results" Value="50" />
     <asp:ListItem Text="100 Results" Value="100" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind I am trying to set the selected value based upon a query to the database.

```
protected void SetResultsDropDown()
        {
            string selectCommand = String.Format("SELECT ResultsReturned FROM StoredFilters WHERE SecurityUserID = {0}", securityUserId);
            string resultValue = DatabaseUtilities.QueryDatabase(selectCommand, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["informconnectstring"].ToString(), "ResultsReturned");
           //based upon the users id the db stores the set number from the drop down the default is 10 however if the number changes when the page loads I want the user to see what their current result set being returned is in the drop down vs. it defaulting to the first option
            ddResultNum.ClearSelection();
            switch (resultValue)
            {
                case "10":   
                    ddResultNum.Items[0].Selected = true; 
                    break;
                case "20":
                    ddResultNum.Items[1].Selected = true; 
                    break;
                case "30":
                    ddResultNum.Items[2].Selected = true;
                    break;
                case "40":
                    ddResultNum.Items[3].Selected =true;
                    break;
                case "50":
                    ddResultNum.Items[4].Selected = true;
                    break;
                case "100":
                    ddResultNum.Items[5].Selected = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I have tried calling this method using onInit as well as during the page load

```
protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            // Extract an Inform User ID from the Token.
            IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = ((IClaimsPrincipal)(Thread.CurrentPrincipal)).Identities[0];
            securityUserId = Convert.ToInt64(claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(c =>
                c.ClaimType == AuthenticationConstants.INFORM_USER_ID_CLAIM_TYPE).First().Value);

            SetResultsDropDown();
        }
```

While the switch steps through and updates object I never see the text within the drop down menu update. It always stays set to the first item of 10 results.

I have tried wrapping the control in an udpatepanel and then calling an update on the panel to see if I could force the refresh on render and page load.

I have also tried instead of using `Items[0].Selected` I have tried to set the selected index as:

```
protected void SetResultsDropDown()
{
string selectCommand = String.Format("SELECT ResultsReturned FROM StoredFilters WHERE SecurityUserID = {0}", securityUserId);
string resultValue = DatabaseUtilities.QueryDatabase(selectCommand, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["informconnectstring"].ToString(), "ResultsReturned");
ddResultNum.ClearSelection();
ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = ddResultNum.Items.FindByValue(resultValue);
}
```

and still no luck. I'd appreciate any help on figuring out why this drop down menu fails to update and represent / display the correct text for what is stored in the database.

-Cheers

Comment: you can use ddResultNum.SelectedValue = .. but in any case your code should work - check your resultValue - is it relevant? or maybe it's always 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `DropDownList.SelectedValue` property???

For example:

```
ddResultNum.SelectedValue = resultValue;
```

Comment: Because selected value does not work. This approach works fine when you are binding the control at runtime to a collection but when the control has pre-defined values it does not seem to update. Using SelectedValue or SelectedIndex does set the control in code to the correct item but this does not update within the UI. when you view the control once the page loads it is set to the first option in the select (result 10)

Comment: Can you post the code as I'm missing something somewhere. If I step through in code it updates but never updates within the Ui

Comment: I went back and programatically built the control and it works. After some more digging into it the problem appears to be related to the CSS that is assigned to the control which is overriding the selected value index. My original block of code works as well as your suggestion (once I remove the css class). For some reason applying CSS to the control reverts it back to the default value. Thanks for pushing me to keep digging, your validation that it works drove me to build if from code to see how it was being created. - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `SelectedIndex` property on the DDL itself. Like so (remember, the index is zero-based):

```
        switch (resultValue)
        {
            case "10":   
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 0;
                break;
            case "20":
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 1; 
                break;
            case "30":
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 2;
                break;
            case "40":
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 3;
                break;
            case "50":
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 4;
                break;
            case "100":
                ddResultNum.SelectedIndex = 5;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: it's not necessary - the current code should work as well. btw the best choice will be using "SelectedValue"

Comment: @BurundukXP: Why would SelectedValue be the best choice?

Comment: "Index" is just one more unnecessary dependency. if you already have a value you don't need to add one more step to understand which item should be selected. and it will be easier for support - if values or order of items can be changed.

Comment: @ShaiCohen this approach does not work, using the above code or the selected value do not update the control in the UI if the values are hard coded for some reason vs binding to a list or collection. While it does set the value in code it is never pushed through to the UI. As a result the code picks up that the value in the DB is 40 but when the page renders the control displays the first option.